# Stop Laravel from updating 'updated_at' on user login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

There does not appear to be any solution on Google searches for this. When logging into an account with Auth in Laravel, it updates the updated_at field for the user. I wish for it to not do this, and only update the updated_at for when the user details actually change.

How could I achieve this in Laravel 4?

UPDATE
I realise why it is updating the timestamp. This is because on user login, I update a field. Which obviously in turn updates the timestamp.

The question should be, how could I stop this update of a field updating the field?

Sample code:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))){
        $user = User::find(Auth::user() -> id);
        $user -> online = 1;
        $user -> timestamps = false;
        $user -> save();

        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }else{
        return Redirect::route('home') -> with('global', 'Failed to login');
    }
}

public function getLogout(){
    $user = User::find(Auth::user() -> id);
    $user -> online = 0;
    $user -> timestamps = false;
    $user -> save();

    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::route('home');
}
```

This is the updated code with the suggestion. This is still updating 'updated_at'.

I suspect it is Auth::logout() updating this but cannot find any documents relating to this.

Comment: Just a note on the side; you can use `$user = Auth::user()` - the user() method returns an User object if authenticated.

Comment: The question is - does it belong to the users table at all?

Comment: @RobGordijn that's helpful to know, thanks!

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Why would it not belong in the users table?

Comment: @Darryl it reflects some temporary state of the app, not the user, so I wouldn't put it there.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk you are talking about the online field correct? This field is used to display to other users about whether a specific user is online. The 'online' property belongs to a user. A user is online, so I don't understand why a users property will be elsewhere.

Comment: Like I said it is not user's data, but application state, that's why it doesn't belong to the users table. Apart from that you can use `->timestamps = false;` it will do the job.

Comment: I still don't understand about it being applications state. Regardless, I use $user->timestamps and it doesn't update on login, but does update on logout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set this in your log in method, it will disable the time-stamps from updating.

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user() -> id);
$user->online = 1;

// disable the timestamps before saving
$user->timestamps = false;
$user->save();
```

**Edit:**
As Jarek Tkaczyk pointed out; the users state doesn't really belong in the `User` model. It also has a serious flaw, what if the users doesn't log out but instead his session expires?

You should instead use the sessions to figure out if a user is online (logged in and active), this is easy to do if you store the sessions in a database. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#database-sessions

Comment: Updated original post. However it looks that your post may still remain to be my answer, so I will explore this.

Solution tested and appears to not be working. Could I clarify that $post in your example is $user in my example?

Comment: Yes, I was a bit quick with the copy paste from my code :)

Comment: Gotcha. Doesn't appear to be working for me however. I feel like the login bit is working, however the logout is not but not sure. Updated original post to include more, and updated code.

Comment: I find it strange if this does not work for you, I successfully use it to increase a post view counter without updating the post timestamps.

Comment: I have done some testing and the login now doesn't update 'updated_at'. However the logout does. I feel like maybe Auth::logout() is updating it?

Comment: I find that hard to believe. But I have to agree with @JarekTkaczyk, I would not have this type of information in my user model. You can work out who is online by the active sessions, this is easy if you store sessions in the database.

Comment: The code shown is in my controller. Where you say User model, do you mean the User.php in the models folder, or the users table? I use User.php purely as an easy access to the table. Also, I will look into database sessions. However I still feel I need to understand the temporary state.

Comment: Your controller works with the `User` class which comes from the `User` model, which in turns accesses the `users` table.

Comment: I see. So would I be correct in saying the online field shouldn't be in the users table? (Although I see database sessions are a solution)

Comment: Yes. Your current method has a serious flaw, what if the user doesn't explicitly log out? But his session times out? Working with sessions would reveal that, your current methods does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to update created_at and updated_at columns while inserting and updating the record,  set the $timestamps property on your model to false.

Like this:-

```
class User extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'users';

   public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Comment: This would work if I wished to have the whole user table not update stamps. However, I only wish the login/logout functions to not update updated_at.